# NSDateFormatter dateFrom String with era

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I am trying to parse dates that only consist of years like
**145** or **123 BC**
into NSDate Objects - with not much success so far.

```
NSDateFormatter f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[f setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[f setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[f setDateFormat:@"y GG"];
date = [f dateFromString:yearString];
```

yearString contains e.g. **145** or **123 BC**

The results are:
I get nil if I specify the era (GG) in the dateFormat.
If I just specify the year (y) in setDateFormat and the year I parse is 145 I get a date, but it is actually 1 hour *before* 145.

Two questions:
 1. What is the proper way to parse years with era suffixes into NSStrings? 
 2. Why do I get the hour difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get `nil` from the formatter if you don't include an era suffix, as is the case for '145'. Make it '145 AD', and I think you'll find it works. The date format components aren't optional — you have to match the whole pattern.

Comment: yes your right. But even with a date like 145 BC i get nil with a dateformatter like 'y GG'

Comment: ok - you where right. it works like you said. I must have had a typo somewhere or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

> how come the hour difference?

Your time zone is probably GMT+1. So you're not actually getting a date one hour earlier but (because your date formatter is set to your time zone), you are parsing the date as `145-01-01 00:00 +0100`. When you now output the date with `-[NSDate description]`, it will give you the equivalent point in time in GMT, which is `144-12-31 23:00 +0000`.

Comment: hm. ok... so what you say is: the date is right, just the nslog output is not correctly adjusted to my timezone, right ? so nothing to worry here. Is that right ?

Comment: ok - you where right. it works like you said. I must have had a typo somewhere or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this problem myself. @OleBergmann's answer to the second part of your question is correct, but although @bosmac's answer to the main part of your question is technically right, it's not very helpful.

Here's what I did...

```
func laxDate(str: String) -> Date? {
    let strictDF = DateFormatter()
    strictDF.dateFormat = "yyyy GG"
    let laxDF = DateFormatter()
    laxDF.dateFormat = "yyyy"

    if let d = strictDF.date(from: str) {
        return d
    } else if let d = laxDF.date(from: str) {
        return d
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

print(String(describing: laxDate(str: "1901"))) // "Optional("1901-01-01 00:00:00 +0000")\n"
print(String(describing: laxDate(str: "10 BC"))) // "Optional("-0009-01-01 00:01:15 +0000")\n"
```

Or, more tersely...

```
func laxDate(str: String) -> Date? {
    func df(_ f: String) -> Date? {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = f
        return df.date(from: str)
    }

    return df("yyyy GG") ?? df("yyyy")
}
```